# with NSURLSession how to get received data or temp file location on cancelling downloadtask

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am downloading multiple files using `NSURLSession`, I want to save downloaded data even on cancelling **download task** and on resume want to start download for the remaining data.
My

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

is not getting called.

This My Code to download:

```
sessionConfig =[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"Download Manager"];

sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess=!_UseOnlyWiFi;

sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost=1;

queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount=1;

session =[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                                         delegate:self
                                                    delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask=[session downloadTaskWithURL:dwurl ];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: have you assigned delegates NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate

Comment: yes other delegate methods are getting called

Comment: you have written datatask and you should have to write download task delegates

Answer (score 0):

```
`you have implemented datatask delegate but created download task implement this`

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                                       didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
                                  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
                          totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
instead of
(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Comment: I have already implemented this method and its working but this method doesn't returns downloaded data. I want to save partially downloaded data to .part file

Comment: its a download task why you want to save partially completed file.

Comment: to resume Download task from where I was paused or canceled task

Comment: it will automatically resume downloading thats why when you first call downloadtask resume it starts downloading wether it is resuming or starting first time downloading

Comment: but if I paused download task and turned off My network connection and resumed it after making network on it dose not  get resumed.

Comment: how you are pausing download task?

Comment: [downloadTask suspend];

Comment: and [downloadTask resume]; to resume

Comment: when data is resuming ?

Comment: it's not getting resumed, it gets resume only in normal conditions like network is running properly and then you paused and resumed download task

Comment: check your app is having background fetch permission in project settings

Comment: yes if your are disconnecting network without pausing download and connecting again then download gets resumed automatically.

Comment: problem gets created only when pause or resume actions are performed before or ofter disconnecting.

Comment: check wether your data connections delegates are getting called or not when you switch on/off wifi .add a print statement in that.

Comment: yes download resumes after some time but it restarts download.

Comment: may be your server is not giving facility of resuming download.some servers does not provide resuming facility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using

```
cancelByProducingResumeData:
```

It says on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSessionDownloadTask/cancelByProducingResumeData:):

> ```
> Cancels a download and calls a callback with resume data for later use.
> ```